# How to check if files exist in My Network Places directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I want to do something like this.

```
import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
        print files
```

However, the directory I want to check is under My Network Places, and the path is "\blue01\syng\getem\BY", and python says that there is no such directory.  Why can't python see this directory?  Does it have something to do with the fact that is under My Network Places?

Comment: try putting the path to the directory as something like `r"\\192.168.1.XXX\c$\whateverpath\mydir"` the reason its not working is because `/mydir` is not in same directory as the python file being run. so you need to be more explicit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say for example, the python file is located on your desktop, it will be something like this:

```
c:\users\yourname\desktop\python_file.py
```

and your target is located at

```
\blue01\syng\getem\BY\mydir
```

inside of the python_file.py if you mention `/mydir` its going to first check the directory that its in ( which would be the desktop) and then its going to check your system path. ( [learn how that stuff works because it will be useful later, but for now just forget about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29))

since `c:\users\yourname\desktop\` != `\blue01\syng\getem\BY`

its gonna have NO idea what you are talking about.

open a window and browse to your target directory, and then copy the address bar

on windows, if its in your network places, the entire path is gonna look something like:

`\\someIPaddress_or_domain\some_form_of_directory_structure\blue01\syng\getem\BY\mydir`

just paste that into python, put it in double quotes and put an `r` in front of it ( to avoid escaping charachters )

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"\\someIPaddress_or_domain\some_form_of_directory_structure\blue01\syng\getem\BY\mydir"):
```

**So TL;DR put exact paths.**